# c# convert from object to model type

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, changetype

I have an empty list with models of type 'audi_b9_aismura' which I want to populate with an object which I retrieve from another list.

I know this object is of the type specified (audi_b9_aismura) but I cannot add it to the list, using Convert.Changetype does not work either. The code below throws (at design time) the following error: Cannot convert from 'object' to '.audi_B9_aismura'.

```
List<audi_b9_aismura> dataList = new List<audi_b9_aismura>();

if (obj.GetType().Equals(typeof(audi_b9_aismura)))
                    {
                        dataList.Add(Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(audi_b9_aismura)));
                    }
```

I also tried, which does not work either.

```
audi_b9_aismura testVar = Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(audi_b9_aismura));
```

And, which converts it ok, but when adding it says again it is of the type object.

```
var testVar = Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(audi_b9_aismura));
dataList.Add(testVar);
```

If I retrieve the object type by filling it in a string, it returns the correct type (audi_b9_aismura)

```
string result = Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(audi_b9_aismura)).GetType().ToString();
```

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType()` returns an object, you still need to cast it to the correct type, as casting is ALL you need to do in this case, `Convert.ChangeType` serves no purpose.

Comment: If you just want to cast items from one type to another, you can use LINQ's Cast<> or OfType<> operators

Comment: I find it strange, that the string result gets filled with the correct type. I am new to programming in C#, so probably I understand wrongly, but if I retrieve the type from the "object" and it is set to the type (audi_b9_aismura) which I want, how come it is not really set to the type when I try to fill a variable with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not do a simple cast :

```
if (obj is audi_b9_aismura)
{
    dataList.Add((audi_b9_aismura)obj);
}
```

As Ben Robinson said in his comment, `Convert.ChangeType()` returns an `object` that still has to be cast to the right type.

Comment: Well, that works! Thanks! However, I don't get why converting it to a different type doesn't work, but this does. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: Makes sense, but it is a shame that by defining the custom type to convert to, it does not really convert to the custom type. Edit: Ohh you removed your comment...

Comment: Yes, this didn't come from that, but from what Ben Robinson said in his comment.

Comment: LINQ already provides Cast and OfType operators, no need to create the temporary list or for the type check and cast.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ provides the [Cast<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) and [OfType<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) methods that allow you to cast or filter object by a speficic type respectively.

To retrieve items of a specific type as a list you can write:

```
var dataList=sourceList.OfType<audi_b9_aismura>().ToList();
```

If you are sure that the source contains only items of the specific type, you can write:

```
var dataList=sourceList.Cast<audi_b9_aismura>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
List<audi_b9_aismura> dataList = new List<audi_b9_aismura>();

if (obj is audi_b9_aismura)
{
    dataList.Add((audi_b9_aismura)obj);
}
```